# How often can heart statues be triggered in 1.3?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria 1.3, [Heart Statues](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_statue) appear to only be triggerable once every 10 seconds. This appears to differ from the previous patches, in which the statue could conceivably be triggered 6 times at once (one for each wiring connection). Was this change introduced in 1.3?

What are some alternate ways that hearts can be generated or farmed?

Comment: Not really, Afaik the cooldown was always 10 seconds. And no... In regards to hearts, we only got heart statues.

Comment: I'm aware that the cool down has always been 10 seconds, but previously, that was _per wiring connection_. In essence, you could get as many as 6 hearts from a single statue every 10 seconds. Now it appears that you can only get 1. This makes my setup for fighting the Golem that much more difficult.

Comment: Oh yeah after a scan of the comments in the wikia it appears the statues started allowing multiple connections after 1.2. It may have been introduced as a bug. So yeah that was probably removed in 1.3. Patch notes do not show changes about that though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ability to trigger statue mechanisms once every ten seconds *per connection* was a bug, and was fixed in the 1.3 patch, as detailed in the patch notes:

> - ...
> - Fixed bug where Worms would not drop gore segments on death.
> - **Fixed a bug where you could spawn a heart/enemy from a statue using wires faster than intended..**
> - Fixed a bug where the game could crash if the Rod of Discord was used on the far right of the world.
> - ...

<sub>[source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/1.3.0.1)</sub>

Statue mechanisms are now triggered at most once every ten seconds irrespective of how many connections they have.

Comment: Well, there goes my heart farm. :-/ Thanks for the info; I somehow missed that in the change log.

Comment: @JonahBishop I've just realised I completely missed the second part of your question... If you've got access to Vampire Knives and a high level melee set you might find farming the Golem a bit easier. With VK I rarely struggle against *most* bosses. Moon Lord is another matter entirely...