# Heart Statues are only dropping one heart until the last is picked up

Tags: terraria

My heart statues only spawn one heart each until I pick the hearts up, after which they spawn another one.

How can I get them to spawn more hearts before I pick them up?

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of things to note:

- As of PC version 1.3, [hearts only spawn **at max** once every 10 seconds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227617/how-often-can-heart-statues-be-triggered-in-1-3). They won't spawn any faster. As such there is no need to create anything better than a 5-second timer; in fact, a 3-second timer can be counterproductive.
- Just leaving your input on constantly won't help. If you are using a pressure plate, step on and off it again. If you are using a lever, make sure you turn it on and off again.
- If there are more than 3 hearts in a 18.75 tile radius, or 6 hearts in a 50 tile radius, or more than 10 anywhere in the world, **no more hearts will spawn.** [Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_statue)

Answer (score 2):

Note that heart statues don't keep spawning the hearts when you're on a pressure plate. You need to get out of it, and step again for another heart.

Either ou keep stepping in and out of the presse plate(or any other way of activating it), or use the timers(1s recommended since hearts are generated every 8 seconds, using a 3s timer would have a small loss in the long term).